# Three.js list of random points

Tags: javascript, three.js

**Beginner question:**
I create some random points in java script. How can I later "call" each single one of them? I believe it was called an Object (the list of all points), where I can manipulate their position in the list or "pull" the ones I need. How do I do that in js?

what is the line:

`var dots = [];` for?
The comment after that was added from another person and I don't get it.

How can I make a line between two points (let's say the first and second from the list - the 0 and the 1)  in Three.js?

**More complicated question:**  I create here X (in this case 20) random points in java script. I am trying to figure out a way to randomly create faces using groups of 3 points and form a mesh.

Well, not so randomly, because I need a result, where all faces bind together in a continuous mesh. The result should look like a terrain poly-surface made out of the many vertex points.

What rules should be applied? 
[image]

```
var numpoints = 20;
var dots = []; //If you want to use for other task

for (var i = 0 ; i < numpoints ; i++) {
    var x = Math.random() * (80 - 1) + 1  //Math.random() * (max - min) + min
    var y = Math.random() * (80 - 1) + 1
    var z = Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1

    var dotGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    dots.push(dotGeometry);
    dotGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z));
    var dotMaterial = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial( { size: 3, sizeAttenuation: false, color: 0xFF0000 });
    var dot = new THREE.PointCloud( dotGeometry, dotMaterial);
    scene.add(dot);
}
```

Comment: The grouping is a little harder because of what is considered an upface (unless you use a two sided material, which is more intense to process I think), an upface is clockwise around the axises, so you would have to find a way to examine them as clockwise points... That's complicated. But you can easily create points (`new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z)`), add them to a geometry (new THREE.Geometry.vertices.push(point1, point2, ...)). To create the faces you could use `new THREE.Face3(pointVertexIndex1, pointVertexIndex2, pointVertexIndex3)` (push to Geometry.faces).

Comment: `var dots = [];` is identical to `var dots = new Array()`. The comment is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

To get a random element from array:

```
function randChoice(array){
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
};
```

There are 2 method to generate a mesh from random points that I know of:
[convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) and [alpha shape](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alpha-shape). Creating a mesh by repeating picking 3 random points would almost surely result in spaghetti.

If you just want to generate terrain like in the picture, there is [terrain generation from heightmap](http://www.chadvernon.com/blog/resources/directx9/terrain-generation-with-a-heightmap/).